# Cant trigger a jquery drag event properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, drag, eventtrigger

I'm trying to trigger the drag event of a div named ts1 when user drags the mouse anywhere in the body.

the div ts1 has a drag function on it (jquery tagsphere). What i'm trying actually to achieve is to trigger $('#ts1').tagsphere() or something

after about 3-4 hours testing and looking for answers, this is my best result:

```
$('body').bind("drag dragstart dragend",function(event){
            $("#ts1").trigger(event);
            return false;
        });
```

**BUT** this still doesn't trigger it....

why? what am i doing wrong? is there a solution out there already that works? cant seem to find 1

**EDIT**

Sorry guys...seems to be too complicated for me..abandoning post.

It seems the dragging function isn't bound to 'ts1' but rather a different element created by the tagsphere function, thus making my question irrelevent.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on drag? As it is, unless you are calling `stopPropagation` on drag, dragstart and dragened events for #ts1 as well, you are getting "too much recursion", is that the `$("#ts1").trigger(event);` will bubble up from `#ts1` to the body, and call itself again because event is too general. Try changing `event` to just `"drag"` first.

Comment: the div *ts1* has a drag function on it [(jquery tagsphere)](http://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com). What i'm trying actually to achieve is to trigger $('#ts1').tagsphere() or something

Comment: @minikomi the _too much recursion_ error isn't showing anymore, after i put a div around it and put stop Propagation on that too..no more recursion but it seems not no work(my solution) thx though.

Answer (score 0):

use `triggerHandler` instead of `trigger`   :

```
$('body').bind("drag dragstart dragend",function(event){
                    $("#ts1").triggerHandler('drag');
                    return false;
                });
```